# Unable to have different links for plugin card and where view more takes you

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Is there a way to have the link that is displayed in the plugin be different from where the view more link takes the user? We want to have a specific design for the plugin card but when the user clicks view more have them go to a completely different url.

Tried using the secondary redirect uri

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [Designing and Developing Plugins](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/) guide, there are two different ways to activate the *Expanded View* from the *Card Face*:

1. Configuring a primary action button
2. Using the Plugin Bridge

In your case, it sounds like you're using a configured primary action button so I'll start with that option. The [Configuration](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/configuration/) for a plugin allows you to configure an [External Application](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/externalapplications/) for the Card Face and also one for the Expanded View. It's very common to have both the Card Face and Expanded View configured to use the *same* External Application, but you can configure them to use *different* External Applications. In that case, the Expanded View would be activated from the action button and go to a different URL than the Card Face.

The other option is to use the [Plugin Bridge](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/). This provides a powerful and configurable way to control how links work for your plugin, but bear in mind that you'll have to incorporate the `@jack-henry/banno-plugin-framework-bridge` JavaScript module into your specific tech stack to accomplish this.